# What will be the Custom Validator for password pattern checking having at least one uppercase,lowercase and number

Tags: angular, customvalidator

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS,Validator,Validators,AbstractControl,ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[checkPattern][formControlName],[checkPattern][formControl],[checkPattern][ngModel]',
    providers: [
        { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => PatternValidator), multi: true }
    ]
})
export class PatternValidator implements Validator {
    constructor() {}

    validate(c:AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } {
        // self val
        let obj:any ={};
        let number:RegExp=new RegExp("/[0-9]/g")
        let capital:RegExp=new RegExp("/[A-Z]/g")
        let letter:RegExp=new RegExp("/[a-z]/g")
if(!number.test(c.value))
            {
                obj.patternNumber=true;
            }
            else
            if(obj.patternNumber)
            delete obj.patternNumber

            if(!capital.test(c.value))
            {
                obj.patternCapital=true;
            }
            else
            if(obj.patternCapital)
            delete obj.patternCapital

            if(!letter.test(c.value))
            {
                obj.patternLetter=true;
            }
            else
            if(obj.patternLetter)
            delete obj.patternLetter

            return obj;
```

password can be:1wWrt
password can't be : 1wwwrt,11111,wwww,WWWWW
{password should have at least one uppercase , one lowercase, one number and minimum 8 characters. 
No only uppercases ,lowercases and numbers are allowed

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: what will be the custom Validator for the pattern having at least one uppercase,one lowercase, one number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex enforces at least 8 character with one uppercase, one lowercase and one number.

`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$`

I used it a with additional characters instead of numbers

```
<mat-form-field class="input-row">
  <input matInput formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="{{ 'Password' | translate }}" required pattern="^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$">
  <mat-error>{{'Doesn't match password criteria' | translate}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```