# Angular 6 url pattern validator

Tags: javascript, angular, pattern-matching

In an input form Angular 6 I want to check if the input url supposed to contain the Facebook url really is a valid url which contains as substring either the string “facebook.com” or “fb.me” and if it is not the case return an error message.

Im stuck with the following:

```
<div nxRow>
  <div nxCol="12">
    <nx-formfield nxStyle='negative' nxLabel="FACEBOOK">
      <input nxInput type="url" ng-model="facebook" pattern="^.*facebook.com*$/" value="{{facebook}}">
      <span nxFormfieldHint>
                  Link zur Facebook
              </span>
    </nx-formfield>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13821385/7124761

Comment: You're asking about Angular 6 but there's AngularJS (1.x) syntax in your code - which version are you using?

Comment: Angular 6, my problem is that pattern is not affecting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a dot before the `*` like `^.*facebook.com.*$` to match any character zero or more times.

Right now you are repeating the `m` zero or more times.

To check if the string contains either facebook.com of fb.me you might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

[`^.*(?:facebook\.com|fb\.me).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/d5BOTY/1)

Comment: No particular experience on that part but perhaps [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626203/what-will-be-the-custom-validator-for-password-pattern-checking-having-at-least) might be helpful.

Comment: Hey man, is there a way to obtain the same result and avoid combination with withespaces?